# SSL Question - about "Unknown Authority"

Tags: server, email, postfix, ssl

I went to sslforfree gave my csr info to them and I recieved 2 files from them: 
1. ca_bundle
2. certificate.crt

I also have my original mydomain.key & the mydomain.csr
I then put my .key and certificate.crt files in the exact same places you'll also find dovecot.pem, same permissions and owners, I also symlinked those files to /etc/dovecot/private , I then restarted postfix and dovecot, my mailserver works great, in testing it at https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers that The mailservers of mail.mydomain.net can be reached through an encrypted connection I'm getting this error saying "Unknown Authority" even though it shows the Authority: Certificate chain

```
mail.mydomain.net
    89 days remaining 2048 bit sha256WithRSAEncryption 
    Unknown Authority 
    Let's Encrypt Authority X3
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 postfix, dovecot, sasl, spamassassin and Webmin everything updated to latest daily. I've been trying to figure this one out for about 2 weeks 12 hours per day, I could really use some help !

Answer (score 0):

I "FINALLY" figured it out, Ilyak - I've been learning for like 2 weeks now everything I can. 
In my case I have 3 files
1. hostname.key I produced
2. ca_bundle.crt
3. certificate.crt

with postfix and dovecot it is obviouse where the first 2 go, I finally found 1 postfix setting that had an entry where I could give it the path example:
"TLS certificate authority file" : /etc/pki/dovecot/private/ca_bundle.crt , I couldn't find one for dovecot, it completes the chain through postfix only, re-tested and VIOALA all green now.

So from what I gathered, is it seems like this may have changed over different versions, One link above like many others I've tried suggest making all 3 files into 1, now the postfix I have on Ubuntu 18.04 takes all three files without any modification, in fact every time I catted more than one together, it wouldn't work at all. So all I ever had to do was make my key, make a csr, use the csr info to get a cert and then download the 2 files from sslforfree and set the path to 2 files in dovecot and all 3 in postfix restart both and done. When I need to replace the certificate I will use the same names and just download them replacing the old ones and restart dovecot and postfix.